# Deferred breakpoints: when are classes loaded

Tags: java, debugging, maven-3, jdb

I am trying to debug maven with: `jdb -attach 8000`, after using `mvnDebug`.

I try to put breakpoints, but get:

```
main[1] stop in DeployMojo.DeployMojo
Deferring breakpoint DeployMojo.DeployMojo.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
main[1] stop at Dependency:66
Deferring breakpoint Dependency:66.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
```

When I run, the breakpoints are not called. I have the sources (generated with a maven command), but how can I make them available to the debugger?

Is there a class loader where I could put a breakpoint?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may happen because your class names are wrong or because you omitted the package.
If class `Dependency` is in package `com.my.package`, then break in class `com.my.package.Dependency` and not in `Dependency`.

Comment: It works. Now, I have a stack, but `list` gives: `Source file not found: MojoExecutor.java`. How can I make the sources available to the debugger? Sorry: `use`... Thanks!

Comment: Apart that: `main[35] use /home/emagiro/tmp/maven/maven-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal
main[35] list
Source file not found: MojoExecutor.java`

Comment: try using -sourcepath <dir1:dir2:...>

Comment: Thanks... that's a command line option. There is a `use/sourcepath` command inside jdb, which I cannot get to work. Still trying.

Answer (score 0):

I was using `jdb -attach -sourcepath ~/path/to/project/main/java`. Turns out jdb doesn't like the `~` and needs `jdb -attach -sourcepath $HOME/path/to/project/main/java` or the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

For me tibtof's answer was only half what I needed ot make it work. After I explicitly added the package name, jdb would yield "Try compiling with debugging on" on this gradle project of mine:

```
> Unable to set deferred breakpoint package.ClassName:LineNumber : No linenumber information for package.ClassName.  Try compiling with debugging on.
```

In this case, if you are using gradle you need to make sure that `options.debug=true` in the `compileJava` task, which you can check with the `println` below.

In my case I was compiling with debugging on - or so I thought. I had my `build.gradle` like so (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543803/7050476) and [this article](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/adfz/fafz/14.1?topic=analyzer-generating-debugging-information-common-java-build-tools)):

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:all' << '-Werror' << '-g'
    options.debug = project.hasProperty('debug')
    options.debugOptions.debugLevel = 'source,lines,vars'
    options.debugOptions.debugLevel = 'source,lines,vars'
    doLast {
      println "Args for for $name are $options.allCompilerArgs"
      println "debug=$options.debug"
    }
}
```

When I ran `./gradlew build -Pdebug` it printed as expected:

```
Args for for compileJava are [-Xlint:all, -Werror, -g]
debug=true
```

It turns out that when I later run `./gradlew runMyTask --debug-jvm` it re-ran the `compileJava` task because I did not pass `-Pdebug` again. Running gradle with `--info` confirms it:

```
Task ':compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Value of input property 'options.debug' has changed for task ':compileJava'
```

This fact only became apparent after a few hours when I added the aforementioned `println`:

```
afarah@gentoopc $ ./gradlew runMyTask --debug-jvm

> Task :compileJava
Args for for compileJava are [-Xlint:all, -Werror, -g]
debug=false

> Task :runMyTask
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

So the solution was to run `./gradlew runMyTask --debug-jvm -Pdebug`, i.e. pass `-Pdebug` again:

```
afarah@gentoopc $ ./gradlew runMyTask --debug-jvm -Pdebug

> Task :compileJava
Args for for compileJava are [-Xlint:all, -Werror, -g]
debug=true

> Task :runMyTask
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Notice `debug=true` now, and finally jdb did not complain and stopped at my LineNumber breakpoint.