# JDB breakpoints not registering

Tags: java, jdb

I'm attempting to debug my program with jdb. I have compiled with -g on javac, but I'm not able to set any breakpoints in my code. The ones I do set are disregarded by jdb, which runs my entire program and then exits.

Can someone help me with jdb?

Filesystem layout:

```
ls org/a/b/
Class1.java Class1.class Class2.java Class2.class MainClass.java MainClass.class ...
```

What I've attempted so far:

```
jdb org.a.b.MainClass arg1 arg2
> stop in MainClass.method1
Deferring breakpoint MainClass.method1.
It will be set after the class is loaded.
> run
run org.a.b.MainClass
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
> 
VM Started: <a print message here>

The application exited
```

In my code, the first thing main does is class method1. However, the breakpoint is being completely disregarded by jdb. How can I make jdb stop at this breakpoint? Do I have to set up something else with jdb? FWIW, I'm not using any other .jar files / using the CLASSPATH in any special way to run my program.

Comment: solved and deleted. stop in org.a.b.MainClass.method1 was needed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deferred breakpoints: when are classes loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911704/deferred-breakpoints-when-are-classes-loaded)